# How to clear text field value on history.back()

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, back

I have a ColdFusion condition like this:

```
<cfif txtTaxFileNo neq "">
    <script>
        alert("NPWP Already Exist");
        history.back();
    </script>
    <cfabort>   
</cfif>
```

Assume `txtTaxFileNo` has a value of "123" in the previous page. How can I empty the `txtTaxFileNo` field? I already tried this:

```
<cfif txtTaxFileNo neq "">
    <script>
        alert("#JSStringFormat('NPWP Already Exist')#");
        history.back();
        txtTaxFileNo.value = "";
    </script>
    <cfabort>   
</cfif>
```

However, the textfield on the previous page is not empty. It still has a value of "123". Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use`history.back()` because that restores form state. If you want to load a fresh page, just load a fresh page.

```
<cfif txtTaxFileNo neq "">
    <script>
        alert("NPWP Already Exist");
        window.location = "form URL here";
        // or, if the URL is the same
        window.location.reload(true);
    </script>
    <cfabort>   
</cfif>
```

See [`window.location.reload()` docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload) on MDN.

Comment: thats the problem sir, i have 3 different pages, lets say pages 1, 2, 3. the problem is whenever i navigate the page, the url still same in the page 1, even i go to page 2, 3 or 4 the url still display location on page 1. so if i paste the url, it always back to first page

Comment: All I can tell you that `history.back()` is the wrong thing to do. I can tell you what to do instead. However, I can't tell you which URL to use. It's your application, you must know.

Comment: cgi.http_referrer might come in handy.

Comment: @AntonPrioHutomo Another thing to remember, `txtTaxFileNo` is a ColdFusion variable not a JavaScript variable. So it is not available on the client. It can only be manipulated on the ColdFusion server so a reload is necessary